# Pass image id to JQuery by clicking on the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm animating images using JQuery. I'm using a button to activate the animation.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b1").click(function(){ // b1 is the id of button
        $(#img).animate({left: '+=20px'});   // img is the id of image
    });
});
```

I have five images so when I click on another image, I need to put its id into the `$(#img)` instead of #img. So the second image will be animated.

How do I do this?

Comment: why not have a class on all the images and then use $(this) when any of that class is clicked?

Comment: You could use the data-attribute to store the id of the currently selected image in the button.

Comment: Vatsal - What do you mean by a class?

Comment: NeilDCruz - how I could do this?

Comment: <img id="room1" style="position:absolute; top:50px;" src="../Plans/room1.png" width="163" height="144" />

<button id="b1">Right</button>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // declare a variable to store the selected image
    var selected = null;

    // listen to clicks on all your images
    // note: might want to filter this down to your target images
    $("img").click(function(){
        // save the selected image
        selected = this
    });


    $("#b1").click(function(){
        // animate the selected image
        $(selected).animate({left: '+=20px'});
    });
});
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Actually I need to replace img in $("img") with a variable that holds the id of the image that I have clicked

Comment: I understand, but I think you are missing the point, this is exactly what this code does.You don't need to pass the id, the "$(selected)" statement will take care of that for you.

Comment: No problem, please take a moment to mark this answer as correct (by pressing the grey checkmark on the top-left of this post), if you felt that it addressed your needs. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the image a 'selected' class on click, then animate the selected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".image").click(function() {
        // unselect others
        $(".image").removeClass("selected");
        // reselect this one
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });

    $("#b1").click(function() {
        // animate selected
        $(".image.selected").animate({left:'+=20px'});
    });
});
```

html

```
<img class='image' src="image1"/>
<img class='image' src="image1"/>
<button id='b1'>click</button>
```

this will also allow you to style the selected image, eg:

```
.selected { border: 1px solid pink }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class (like img_to_animate) to images like

```
<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png' style="width:50px;height:50px;" class="img_to_animate" />
<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png' style="width:50px;height:50px;" class="img_to_animate" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(".img_to_animate").click(function(){      
   $(this).animate({left: '+=20px'});
})
```

Comment: It's the button that causes the previously selected image to animate.  Not clicking the image itself.

Comment: Glad if  it helped

Answer (score 0):

This version will move the animated image back to its original position when the button is pushed, if a different image is selected:

```js
$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('img').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
    if ( $(this).attr('data-current-image') !== $('img.active').attr('data-image-id') ) {
      $('img[data-image-id=' + $(this).attr('data-current-image') + ']').animate({left: '10'});
    }
    $(this).attr('data-current-image',$('img.active').attr('data-image-id'));
    $('img[data-image-id=' + $(this).attr('data-current-image') + ']').animate({left: '+20'});
  });
```

```css
img { display: block; position: relative; margin-top: 10px; left: 10px; height: 50px; width: 75px; }
img.active { border-right: 3px solid #f90; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><input type=submit data-current-image=0 value=" Animate! ">
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/LCRO0jJ.jpg' data-image-id=1 class="active" />
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/LCRO0jJ.jpg' data-image-id=2 />
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/LCRO0jJ.jpg' data-image-id=3 />
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/LCRO0jJ.jpg' data-image-id=4 />
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/LCRO0jJ.jpg' data-image-id=5 />
```